# Looking for promotional Power card effects

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

Well, even though they never finished making them, I went and got all the sets of Power cards available, but a few I bought used came with a few extra cards not listed in any of the handbooks. After a bit of research, I learned that there were some sets of minis that were released and some of them had extra Power cards. I've searched everywhere online and found only one place that had images of the cards so I could read the effects of the new powers, but their list is incomplete. I'm hoping that someone here can help me by providing the data of the power cards I'm missing. Two of them I can't even find the names of, sad to say. Here's the list of all the cards I now know the effects of:

### PHB 1:

- Arcing Fire
- Chilling Cloud
- Cutting Words
- Daring Shout
- Eldritch Strike
- Ethereal Sidestep
- Foe to Foe
- Gaze of Defiance
- Grasping Tide
- Hidden Blade
- Hunter's Teamwork
- Knockdown Assault
- Laugh it Off
- Probing Strike
- Repelling Shield
- Walk Among the Wounded

(I know one of the missing cards is Challenging Strike, but nothing else)

### PHB 2:

- Astral Wind
- Clawfoot Berserker Rage
- Clever Strike
- Close the Gap
- Dragon's Tenacity
- Flare of Divine Vengeance
- Focused Fury
- Forbidding Strike
- Frenzied Beast Rage
- Frostwind Blade
- Healing Circle
- Inevitable Wave
- Invigorating Assault
- Leaf Wall
- Refocus
- Shield of Blades
- Unbalancing Force

There's two cards (one per set) that I can't even find the name for. I also realize that some of the powers may not be that great, but I'd love to have the list of their effects, stats, class, etc.) to complete my list of Powers. Thanks in advance to all who can help with this. :)

Comment: They're in the compendium online if you've got DDI access.

Comment: @waxeagle You should make that an answer.

Comment: We can't reproduce that content because it's under copyright, we are not licensed to do so, and it would not be within fair use. :P You can pay for this content, and us distributing it freely would be... not legal.

Comment: This question closed because it has no positive outcomes other than a link to DDI.

Answer (score 5):

These cards, along with most other material published for Dungeons and Dragons 4e, are available through their online subscription service [Dungeons and Dragons Insider](http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Subscription.aspx).

They are available in two ways:

- You can find them by searching the online [D&D Compendium](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/) (Searching is free, access to the information from the search is behind the pay wall).
- You can choose them as power selections when eligible for your character through the online [character builder](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/tool.aspx?x=dnd/4new/tool/characterbuilder).

I cannot give you a full list of the cards right now, but you should be able to filter on source from the compendium.